# How can I solve this error? EditText.getText() returns empty string ""

Tags: java, android, io

I have an error with my Android studio project.
I'm trying to save a file, to do this I get the text of different edittexts and write them on a text file in external storage.
The error here, is that the file only has empty string characters (""), this occurs because the string variables I have are empty, they take the value of the edittext, but they are still empty.

I'm doing this inside the class of My AppCompatDialogFragment

Here's my code:

```
 private ImageButton CloseB;
    private ImageButton SaveB;
    private EditText EditTitle;
    private EditText EditDesc;
    private Spinner TagSpinner;
    private EditText EditDate;
    private EditText EditHour;

    private String Hour;
    private String FileName;
    private String Title;
    private String STag;
    private String Description;
    private String Date;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        AlertDialog Dialog = builder.create();
        LayoutInflater Inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.newtaskdialog, null);
        builder.setView(view);
        CloseB = view.findViewById(R.id.NewTCloseB);
        SaveB = view.findViewById(R.id.SaveBN);

        CloseB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

                SaveB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
                @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Title = EditTitle.getText().toString();
                Date = EditDate.getText().toString();
                Hour = EditHour.getText().toString();
                Description = EditDesc.getText().toString();
                SaveFile();
                //dismiss();
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
      }



    public void SaveFile()
    {
        String State = getExternalStorageState();
        String LTitle = Title.toLowerCase();
        String FileName = Title + ".ard";
        byte Tag = GetTag();
        int ITag = Tag;
        String STag = String.valueOf(ITag);
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(State))
        {
            File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File Dir = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AcardiaFiles"); //<-- Need to check in which folder is making the task
            if (!Dir.exists())
            {
                Dir.mkdir();
            }
            File file = new File(Dir, FileName);
            String Message = "false" + "\n" +  Title + "\n" + Date + "\n" + Hour + "\n" + STag + "\n" + Description;

            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fileOutputStream.write(Message.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File Saved." + Title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog d = getDialog();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newtaskdialog, container, false);
        EditTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.editNTitle);
        EditDate = v.findViewById(R.id.editNDate);
        EditDesc = v.findViewById(R.id.editNDesc);
        EditHour = v.findViewById(R.id.editNHour);
        TAdapter = new TagAdapter(getContext(), tagList);
        TagSpinner = v.findViewById(R.id.TagNSpinner);

        EditDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar C = Calendar.getInstance();

            }
        });
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    }
```

Comment: Do you know that the `EditTitle` etcetera variables are referring to the correct things?  (They are not being initialized when you are initializing the other controls.)  Do you know for sure that `SaveFile` is being called?  If those hints don't help, please reduce this to an MCVE.

Comment: (And please fix your code style, you should NOT start a variable name or method name with an uppercase letter.  And you should be logging exceptions, NOT throwing stacktraces into standard output.  You should get these things right before you start showing your code to other people.)

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for your reply. Yeah, the method does get called, the varibles do refer to the correct views, Curiosly, the views aren´t null, but the text value that the return is empty.  Also, I didn't have idea that is bad starting with Upperscae, could you please explain me why?

Comment: If the view control variables are not null and they are not returning the values that the user has entered, then they are probably point to the wrong view control objects.  I note that you are using a *local* `view` variable in your `onCreateDialog`.

Comment: *" Also, I didn't have idea that is bad starting with Upperscae, could you please explain me why?"* - Because you are ignoring accepted Java style conventions.   If you want other people to read your code, you *should* follow a good style guide (e.g. https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).  It is the socially acceptable thing to do ... for a Java programmer.

Comment: @StephenC I Updated the question with new code